# Why do I get this error while running "npm start"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

I want to write some e2e tests for one app and when I run "npm start" I receive the following error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Rmf.jpg)

C:\Users\saros.LAPTOP-JQTANCVI\OneDrive\Documents\CypressWithTypescript\trelloapp-master\index.js:5
const server = jsonServer.create();
^

TypeError: jsonServer.create is not a function
at Object. (C:\Users\saros.LAPTOP-JQTANCVI\OneDrive\Documents\CypressWithTypescript\trelloapp-master\index.js:5:27)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
PS C:\Users\saros.LAPTOP-JQTANCVI\OneDrive\Documents\CypressWithTypescript\trelloapp-master>

Can somebody explain to me step-by-step how can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: May be because you are running code from onedrive folder

Comment: Could you please explain me how to fix it? Thanks!